# ReactOnRails with jQuery support

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, react-on-rails

Has anyone worked with ReactOnRails previously and had to use jQuery for some external library (select2 in my case)?

How to add jQuery(jquery-ujs) to webpack so I can still use it in my `app/assets` directory, without having to actually install it twice (through the gem and the npm)?

Comment: can you not access the global `window.$` in your react app when its in the app/assets?

Comment: I can't. 
I installed `jquery-ujs` and `jquery` using npm, uninstalled `jquery_ujs` gem and removed related `require` statements. It seems that Rails is checking for jquery everywhere but not inside my node-modules.

Comment: Correct, your old code is looking for the global from the previous installation. you should put that back and direct webpack to look for the global as well.

Comment: Or you'd have to convert all your old JS into the import style code.